# How do you target a parent and child <ul> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, menu

Just a quick one, but I'm having some trouble getting my head around it.

I'm using javascript to detect elements inside a menu:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var list = nav.children.length;
```

But the menu has nested `<ul>` for dropdowns, how do I target these?

Comment: I don't get what you want. What have you tried? What is the expeced result that you need? Do you have a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Thanks @Zim84 - here's what I am doing - http://jsfiddle.net/pFHBa/1/ - I am dynamically creating a menu dropdown list. But for nested <ul> elements I want to add a hyphen infront of them. So it would have <option>- Sub 1</option> thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code and actually reading and seeing your fiddle I removed my other answer as it was misinterpreting what you need...

In short you need to write a recursive function to traverse all the child uls when found. I don't have my development env running so will psuedo code this for you (and I'm sure you'll get the drift)

```
RecursiveFunction(document.getElementById('nav'), "-");
```

//elsewhere

```
function RecursiveFunction(domElement, prependedChar)
{

    //because this is .js you will probably need some closures...
    var currPrependedChar = prependedChar;
    var dom = domElement;

    //iterate all nodes, check if they are a li/a and populate dropdown...
    for(count;count < dom.list.Length;++count){

    //if the element you have found is a ul recurse
    if(dom.list[count] == "ul"){
         RecursiveFunction(dom.list[count], currPrependedChar + currPrependedChar ); //this calls this function
    }else{
         //combobox option.Value = currPrependedChar + elementInnerText
    }
    }
}
```

This is the completed recursive function in fiddle form

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juCqP/22/)

CODE

```
function RecursiveFunction(currDom, currPrependedChar) {

//because this is .js you will probably need some closures...
var prependedChar = currPrependedChar;
var dom = currDom;
var children = dom.children;
var childrenCount = children.length;


//iterate all nodes, check if they are a li/a and populate dropdown...
for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; ++i) {

    var curElem = children[i];
    //if the element you have found is a ul recurse
    switch (curElem.nodeName) {
    case "A":
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = prependedChar + curElem.text;
        option.value = curElem.href;
        select.appendChild(option);
        break;
        default:
            if(curElem.nodeName == "UL") prependedChar += prependedChar
            RecursiveFunction(curElem, prependedChar);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is getting a tad confusing for me though. I have only been writing JS a few weeks. Here is what I have done with your code, is it anywhere in the right direction? http://jsfiddle.net/c2dXx/

Comment: yes you have interpreted correctly though note I have edited my code to introduce something called a closure on the two variables passed in (otherwise you may always get "- option" instead of "- - option"). Recursive functions are a must to understand as are closures in javascript. The gist is the recursive function will keep on drilling down through your list until it finds no more uls to recurse through

Comment: Would I need to wrap this in the 'function RecursiveFunction(nav, '- ') {' function or is it okay to be inline? Really appreciate your help Paul.

Comment: yep the closure variables need to be in the function - in short this means you have a local copy of the variable passed in at call time so you don't end up using the value of the object outside the function when it actually executes (closures... once again have a good read on this single topic if you wish to master javascript)

Comment: Use this as a good learning exercise and if you still haven't cracked it tonight I'll finish up what you have completed tommorow for you todd (you should be fine though from what I have seen)

Comment: Thanks Paul, am I okay to pester you a little further with another JSFiddle snippet? ... And yes a great learning exercise. You've been a massive help, if only beers could be sent via Stack :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21903/discussion-between-paul-sullivan-and-todd)

Answer (score 0):

`nav.getElementsByTagName('ul')` would give you all `<ul>` elements inside `nav`.

For more complex searches in the DOM, you could use [`querySelector/querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) to [select elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) in the way that you apply CSS styles to them (`'#id ul'`, `'.someClass'`, etc.).